# How to iterate through a list of custom type and replace one property from another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below 2 lists:

```
List<decimal>data;
List<Myclass> mylist;//MyClass has a property called MyProp which is of type decimal.
```

which are populated.
Now, I want to iterate through the myList and replace each MyProp with data list.
I can do it through foreach loop, but looking for elegant LINQ solution,any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the replacement criteria? If it's just list index, use [`.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Myclass` have only one property which is `decimal`? is so why you need a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code how it could be done with the Zip method

```
public class Myclass
{
    public decimal MyProp { get; set; }
}

List<decimal> data = new List<decimal>() { 1,2,3,4,5};
List<Myclass> myList = new List<Myclass>() { new Myclass(), new Myclass(), new Myclass()};

data.Zip(myList, (dataItem, myListItem) => 
{
    myListItem.MyProp = dataItem;
    return myListItem;
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `Zip` the two lists together!

```
list.Zip(data,
         (x, y) => x.MyProp = y // this will be run for everything in list
        ).ToList(); // ToList is needed to actually run the query, otherwise it will be deferred.
// now the values should all be assigned.
```